# Copying Mat to raw array in OpenCV with Java? (Getting "multiple of channels count" error)

Tags: java, scala, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to load an image in Scala using OpenCV with the Java bindings. After loading the image, I'd like to convert it to a traditional Scala `Array[Float]`.

Following the suggestions in [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4761/mat-to-byte-array/), I implemented the following code to achieve this:

```
    val image = Highgui.imread(imgName)
    image.convertTo(image, CvType.CV_32FC1) //convert 8-bit char -> single channel 32-bit float

    val s = image.size()
    val height = s.height.asInstanceOf[Int]
    val width = s.width.asInstanceOf[Int]
    val nChannels = image.channels()
    printf("img size = %d, %d, %d \n", height, width, nChannels); // 512, 512, 3

    //thanks: http://answers.opencv.org/question/4761/mat-to-byte-array/
    val imageInFloats = new Array[Float](height * width * image.channels())
    image.get(0, 0, imageInFloats)
```

When compiling the code, I get the following error:

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Provided data element number (1) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (3)

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Provided data element number (1) should 
be multiple of the Mat channels count (3)

    at org.opencv.core.Mat.get(Mat.java:2587)
    at HelloOpenCV$.main(conv.scala:25)
    ...
```

There are a couple of reasons why this error doesn't make sense to me:

- The image should be 1-channel because we do `convertTo(...32FC1)`. Printing `image.channels()` reveals that there are 3 channels. Huh?
- The size of `imageInFloats` is a multiple of `image.channels()`. I think this contradicts the error message about it not being a multiple of the number of channels.

**Why does this code throw the `should be a multiple of Mat channels count` error?**

---

Configuration details:

- [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) 0.12.4
- OpenCV 2.4.9

---

Final notes:

There's a more lightweight Scala library that would work as well as OpenCV for loading images into Scala. I'm using OpenCV at the for this because I've been doing a bunch of other vision stuff in Scala with OpenCV. That said, I'm willing to explore other libraries for image I/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you do like : `Highgui.imread(imgName)` , it loads it as a 3 channel rgb image.

it should work, as you expected, if you either `Highgui.imread(imgName,0)` ( load as grayscale ) or apply cvtColor() to do a manual conversion.

Comment: Ah, good idea. Doing `Highgui.imread(imgName,0)` seems to have resolved the error!